# PHP artisan return Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I tried to run `php artisan` in a project folder using Command Prompt. However, this error keeps popping up:

```
  [ErrorException] 
  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

Running the same command in other projects' folder (With Laravel 4.2 and 5.1) worked fine.

From what I've read on Laracast: any service providers need to be commented out. However, in this particular project I don't have any.

Comment: You mean you run this via CLI? Then there _is_ no HTTP involved, so you can’t expect an HTTP request header of that name (or any other) to be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should verify your controllers constructors or artisan command constructors. They might be launched when running `php artisan` and if in any of them you are using directly `HTTP_USER_AGENT` or launching any piece of code that requires `HTTP_USER_AGENT` it makes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it!

The problem is caused by a line in routes.php. To be specific, the code is designed to filter out IE users by verifying the user agent like this:

```
 if(preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident') !== false))
```

So with artisan (which runs through the CLI), there is no HTTP_USER_AGENT header. That caused this error:

```
  [ErrorException] 
  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

The fix is quite simple. Just add `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) &&` to the if logic like this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident') !== false)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate as beforeRoute middleware?  As well as abstracting that regex into a reusable object that can be added to later on?